# server.sh: 2: .: properties.conf: not found

Tags: linux, sh

I have server.sh file running my rmi server looking like:

```
#!/bin/bash
. properties.conf
SERVER_JAR=SomeRMI-server.jar
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=${publicPath} -jar $SERVER_JAR
```

properties.conf is in the same location as server.sh 
but when I run .sh file I got:

```
server.sh: 2: .: properties.conf: not found
```

error, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the complete path to `properties.conf`:

```
. /complete/path/to/properties.conf
```

or even

```
. ./properties.conf
```

Comment: Be prepared to have to patch the scripts when you relocate them.  Use my answer to avoid this drawback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
. "$(dirname "$0")"/properties.conf
```